# Meteor: Bootstrap data-dismiss=‘modal’ preventing autoform submission

Tags: bootstrap-modal, meteor-autoform

So I am using the autoform and bootstrap package in Meteor. The goal is to be able to create an auto-generated form using autoform inside of a bootstrap modal and then on clicking the submit button create a new object to add to the collection and dismiss the modal.

The problem I am having is that when I add `data-dismiss="modal"` to the submit button it will stop submitting to the collection and just dismiss the modal. Any ideas on what is happening?

Here's what it my modal template looks like below.

```
<template name="goalCreationModal">
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal example</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                     <p> ---- </p>
                     {{#autoForm collection="Goals" id="insertGoalForm" type="method" meteormethod="addGoal"}}
                        <legend>Add a Goal</legend>
                        {{> afQuickField name='title'}}
                        {{> afQuickField name='color'}}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default make-goal" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                    {{/autoForm}}
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was this:

```
         {{#autoForm schema="PostsSchema" id="insertPost" type="method" meteormethod="postEntry"}}
               <div class="modal-body">
                    <fieldset>
                      {{> afQuickField name='title'}}
                      {{> afQuickField name='user' type = 'hidden'}}
                      {{> afQuickField name='content' rows=10}}
                      {{> afQuickField name='tag'}}
                    </fieldset>


               </div><!-- / modal-body -->


                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ask</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
                  </button>
                </div><!-- / modal-footer -->
                {{/autoForm}}
```

Pay attention to the {{autoform}} tags. Try this code, it worked for me.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I tried wrapping the autoform tags as you suggested. It didn't seem to have any affect. Here's a link to what I did: [example](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqoyw/2)

Comment: Now, check three things. First, check the fields in your simple schema. Make sure that you either have fields for all of them in the template or have (optional: true;) in the schema. Second, put the fieldset tags. Third, make sure you do not call any method in Template.events (when you click submit the form aumatically calls the method you specified in the autoform tag).

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with my schema, the goal submits just fine when I remove the data-dismiss attribute. I'm convinced there's a problem with how the events are being fired or caught. My current work around to this issue is to manually call `Modal.hide('goalCreationModal');` on a click event.